# NextJS generate <!-- --> when props are used in return a HTML segment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

```
const City = (context) => {
    return (
        <>
          <Head>
            <title>Fliesenleger in {context.data} - Pro Handwerker</title>
          </Head>
        </>
     )}
```

It Generates-

```
<title>Fliesenleger in <!-- -->Aach<!-- --> - Pro Handwerker</title>
```

But it is only showed in `view-source:` 
Not in rendered page.

These are my Dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "^5.2.2",
        "next": "^13.0.5",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "18.2.0"
    }
```

I Want This-

```
<title>Fliesenleger in Aach - Pro Handwerker</title>
```

Comment: It's due to React internal logic related to server rendering and hydration: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/7500 https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14725 https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24263